# HTML Popover fails in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popover

The following code is supposed to create a bootstrap popover that contains an HTML string called `boomHTML`. Unfortunately, the code only executes properly in bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 4 leads to an empty popover. This is also only the case if I use html tags different from `<h1></h1>`. Somehow, bootstrap sanitizes the input. I have not yet looked into the github repo.

Any help is highly appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

  
  var boomHTML = "<blue>Boooom</blue>";
    
    $('#shapes-trigger').tooltip({
    title: 'Shapes'
  }).popover({
    html : true,
    title: boomHTML,
    placement: 'top'
  }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
  }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#shapes-trigger {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

blue {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <span id="shapes-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true">Hello World</span>
    </div><!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) in bootstrap for popover it says title expects either a string , element or function. Since you are passing HTML its better to pass it as an element rather than string. Passing it as an element fixes the issue.see here [codepen link](https://codepen.io/DasithKuruppu/pen/XGvZqb) or below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

  
  var boomHTML =document.createElement("blue");
  boomHTML.innerText= "BOOOM"
  
    
    $('#shapes-trigger').tooltip({
    title: 'Shapes'
  }).popover({
    html : true,
    title: boomHTML,
    placement: 'top'
  }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
  }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#shapes-trigger {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

blue {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <span id="shapes-trigger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true">Hello World</span>
    </div><!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will do the trick 
Change the **blue** in the css to be a class

In the JS file use the following code i have change few lines of codes

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

  var boomHTML = "<p class='blue'>Boooom</p>";
  var boomTitle = "Title";

    $('#shapes-trigger').tooltip({
    title: 'Shapes'
  }).popover({
    html : true,
    title:boomTitle, 
    content: boomHTML,
    placement: 'top'
  }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('disable');
  }).on('hide.bs.popover', function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('enable');
  });

});
```